# Repeated AccessControlException: Missing permission ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM.1") Errors in Datastax 5.0.1 spark node

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am seeing the following error repeatedly in the logs of several of my Datastax nodes. I haven't been able to find any references for what is causing it, how to prevent it. Why is it trying to exitVM?

```
ERROR [dispatcher-event-loop-3] 2017-04-13 10:39:47,540  Logging.scala:74 - All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
ERROR [dispatcher-event-loop-3] 2017-04-13 10:39:47,540  Logging.scala:95 - Uncaught exception in thread Thread[dispatcher-event-loop-3,5,main]
java.security.AccessControlException: Missing permission ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "exitVM.1")
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.DseJavaSecurityManager.verify(DseJavaSecurityManager.java:36) ~[dse-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at com.datastax.bdp.util.DseJavaSecurityManager.checkPermission(DseJavaSecurityManager.java:44) ~[dse-core-5.0.1.jar:5.0.1]
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(SecurityManager.java:761) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.System.exit(System.java:971) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$Worker$$reregisterWithMaster$1.apply$mcV$sp(Worker.scala:300) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.2.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrExit(Utils.scala:1163) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.2.jar:1.6.1.2]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker.org$apache$spark$deploy$worker$Worker$$reregisterWithMaster(Worker.scala:230) [spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.2.jar:5.0.1]
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Worker.scala:539) [spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.2.jar:5.0.1]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:166) [scala-library-2.10.6.jar:na]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:166) [scala-library-2.10.6.jar:na]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcV$sp(Inbox.scala:116) [spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.2.jar:1.6.1.2]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.safelyCall(Inbox.scala:204) [spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.2.jar:1.6.1.2]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Inbox.process(Inbox.scala:100) [spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.2.jar:1.6.1.2]
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher$MessageLoop.run(Dispatcher.scala:215) [spark-core_2.10-1.6.1.2.jar:1.6.1.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
ERROR [dispatcher-event-loop-3] 2017-04-13 10:39:47,541  Logging.scala:95 - Ignoring error
```